# What does the __init__ method serve for?

Tags: python, class, initialization, init

I started learning python (with no prior knowledge of it, not programming) few weeks ago and am stuck at Classes.
Currently the "**init**" class method confuses me. What does it do, in fact?

Here is an example of the **init** method usage I am copying from particular python book:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name

    def sayHi(self):
       print "Hello, my name is", self.name

p = Person("George")
p.sayHi()
```

Please do correct me, but the same result could be achieved without the _*init* method, like so:

```
class Person:
    def sayHi(self, name):
       print "Hello, my name is", name

p = Person()
p.sayHi("George")
```

Right?

So what is the purpose of the **init** method anyway?

Thank you.

Comment: Of course you *could* do it that way, but then there's no purpose in having a class at all -- you could just `def sayHi(name):...` -- The purpose of a class is to group data (attributes like `name`,`age`,...) along with methods (functions) to work with the data.  Your `Person` class could have an `age` attribute and a `have_birthday` method which incremented the age for example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply mgilson.
In the book I am reading (A byte of python), fields and methods are subcategories of attributes. It seems you are saying opposite?
"_Collectively, the fields and methods can be referred to as the attributes of that class._"

Answer (score 3):

```
__init__
```

in python is similar to constructor in c++ or java.

Comment: Good answer; it is similar. `__init__` is the initializer, while `__new__` is the allocator.

Comment: I have no knowledge of C++, Java or any other programming language.
Thank you.